# How to set the image icon on top right corner beyond the boundary of dialog

Tags: jquery, css, dialog, modal-dialog

[image]

I want to make a customized close button, but the image is cut by the boundary of the dialog. Could someone give me a hint about what is going wrong of this situation.

ps. I have used both dialog of "jquery-ui" and "jquery Modal", they all got the same issue.

Comment: Can you add your code? I think using negative margins should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

The above implies that the children(.span) absolute position is restricted to the parent(.wrapper)

```
.span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px; /* move the top of .span */
  right: 20px; /* move the right of .span */
}

<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="span">X</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.main{
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
  position:relative;
  maigin:0 auto;
}
.main span{
  position: absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:10px;
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<span>X</span>
 <p>Lorem</p>
</div>
```